# What name would you give to data about a person's illnesses, ailments, diseases and medical condition?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What term would you ascribe to the record of a person's illnesses, diseases and medical condition?

**Clarification**

The thing I am trying to describe is simply the record of, or data that reflects on the present medical condition of a patient with respect to diseases and aberrations from good health.

I want to clarify that I am not looking for a term to represent *all kinds of medical data about a person*.

**What I am looking for**

1) I am not necessarily looking for just a single word, but definitely a single descriptor or title between one and four words.

2) I am searching for one of the either two things:

a) *Precision*

Terms like *medical history*, *medical profile* (all encompassing, includes diagnostic reports, health indicators such as BP, sugar level, etc.), *medical records* (suggests only reports about the medical tests a person had), *medical report* (again, suggests a medical test report) -- all have different meanings. I am searching for precision; or

b) *Custom*

Where there isn't a precise term, or even if there is, and there is also a term that is widely known and accepted to be what my question is asking, and even if it is colloquial and doesn't literally mean what I am asking, but is widely accepted, then I am in favor of using it.

Comment: Medical history.

Comment: Not really. The qualification `history` completely distracts from what I am trying to express here.

Comment: You mean it ought to be gender neutral so as not to distract? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use any of this:

> **Case History** -  a record of a person's background, medical history, etc, esp one used for determining medical treatment
>
> **Anamnesis**- a patient's account of their medical history
>
> **Heteroanamnesis**- The medical history or case history of a patient is information gained by a physician by asking specific questions,
>   either of the patient or of other people who know the person and can
>   give suitable information, with the aim of obtaining information
>   useful in formulating a diagnosis and providing medical care to the
>   patient.
>
> History of the present illness (abbreviated HPI)
>
> History of presenting complaint (HPC)

**[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_history)**

Comment: Very nice, Kiran. Thank you very much. Most useful answer so far.

Comment: I think I'll go with *Case History* as it is widely understood to mean exactly what I am asking, or it comes very close.

Comment: Mention the source, include a link to the source where possible. Acknowledge ownership of IP.

Answer (score 2):

*Medical history* and *patient profile* are employed when folks are being stuffy; but on the clinic floor everybody in the hospitals I've worked at and offices I've visited just called it the patient's *chart*.

ADDED, with respect to your further qualifications:

On the one hand, I don't think any responsible medical practitioner would regard any aspect of the patient's medical history as *a priori* irrelevant to the patient's current medical status. She might conclude that this datum or that was irrelevant to what she herself was called upon to understand or act upon in the immediate situation; but that conclusion would come only after weighing **all** the data against each other.

On the other hand, however, there is the fact that this practitioner only rarely **has** much (not to speak of 'all') of the data she would like to have. Usually, she will have only the patient's fragmentary and unreliable or misinformed recollections. A comprehensive 'history' is, in medicine no less than ordinary historiography, a theoretical concept, not a practical reality.

But whatever information she has got or can get will go into the *chart*; and that's what she has to work with.

Comment: Very good answer. Compels me to clarify my question a bit. This answer is a candidate for the right answer. I'll just wait until, and if not.

Comment: I just edited my question to clarify my intent.